# Crash when calling run on boost::asio::io_service

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to write a relatively simple class 'CallbackTimer' that takes an amount of time and a function, and after the amount of time elapses the function is called.  This can be repeated a few times if necessary.

It all works as intended, however I am occasionally getting a crash when I call start a couple of times before the timer has finished, but I can't see where the problem is.  I assume it's because I'm not mixing my threads and the io_service correctly, but I'm not sure.  Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

The class is as follows

```
CallbackTimer::CallbackTimer(const std::function<void()>& callback) :
  callback_(callback),
  currentRepeats_(0),
  //io_(boost::asio::io_service()),
  timer_(new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_)),
  strand_(io_),
  thread_(nullptr)
{
}

CallbackTimer::~CallbackTimer()
{
  cancel();
}

void CallbackTimer::start(size_t intervalMillis, int repeats)
{
  if (thread_)
  {
    cancel();
  }

  requestedRepeats_ = repeats;
  intervalMillis_ = intervalMillis;
  currentRepeats_ = 0;
  runTimer();

  thread_.reset(new std::thread([this]()
  {
    this->io_.run();
  }));

  thread_->detach();
}

void CallbackTimer::cancel()
{
  timer_->cancel();

  if (thread_ && thread_->joinable())
  {
    thread_->join();
  }

  io_.reset();
}

void CallbackTimer::runCallback(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
  if (e == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
  {
    io_.stop();
    return;
  }

  currentRepeats_++;
  callback_();

  if (currentRepeats_ >= requestedRepeats_)
  {
    io_.stop();
    return;
  }

  runTimer();
}

void CallbackTimer::runTimer()
{
  timer_->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(intervalMillis_));
  timer_->async_wait(strand_.wrap(std::bind(&CallbackTimer::runCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At quick glance, there are two potential problems:

- The `CallbackTimer` class fails to guarantee the pre-condition that[`io_service::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) is not invoked when there are unfinished calls to to the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()`, resulting in unspecified behavior.
- `CallbackTimer::runCallback()` may be invoked after the lifetime of the `CallbackTimer` instance has ended, invoking undefined behavior.

Both problems result from no synchronization with the thread running the `io_service`.  The thread is detached after its creation in `CallbackTimer::start()`, and the the if-statement within `CallbackTimer::cancel()` will always be false, causing no synchronization to occur.  This allows for the following cases:

- `io_service::reset()` is invoked while `thread_` is within `io_service::run()`.
- The `CallbackTimer` that owns the `io_service` is deallocated while `thread_` is within `io_service::run()`.

To resolve this, consider no longer detaching from `thread_` so that synchronization may occur.

For further debugging, a stack trace or an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could help in identifying the exact source of the crash.

Comment: You were right, removing the detach call stopped the crash.